# Blazeds Stream Message On Mobile 3G Service

Tags: java, iphone, apache-flex, blazeds, 3g

I have a project that connect to BlazeDs for streaming message service and I cannot make it work on the 3G. Please if you know it is possible I would appreciate your help.

I have working streaming messages and remote on Wi-Fi but the 3G only does remotes. When it try to subscribe to stream on the 3G it say

```
> [BlazeDS]15:59:55.259 Channel endpoint my-streaming-amf received
> request. [BlazeDS]15:59:55.261 Endpoint with id 'my-streaming-amf'
> received a duplicate streaming connection request from, FlexClient
> with id '4998DC8E-420B-87A3-58F0-3B71E040ABEB'. Faulting request.
```

Please if you can help. I can give more information if you need. Thank you.

EDIT: Please, this is serious question. For instance, it say

```
[BlazeDS]17:02:08.479 Number of streaming clients for endpoint with id 'my-streaming-amf' is 1.
```

BUT I am only testing one clientId so how can 1 be connected and I do not receive messages?

Comment: Hi user3735596, I don't know the answer to this question, but I remember in the past seeing a lot of SO questions that said "my Android app works over WiFi but not over 3G" If you search the tag combination [android][3g] or [android][umts] you might find them. There were some answers describing some factors that might be different in the mobile network.

Comment: It might be useful to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969387/multiple-consumers-per-streamingamf-connection